# Tomcat slow loading a big script

Tags: apache, tomcat

on my test server we are running Tomcat 4.1.18 and Apache 2 for https access.
I have a HTML page with a script of size 550KB (sencha script) and my server is very slow loading this page, about 10 sec !!!

How can I make the loading of this script faster ?
Is possible that Apache and https make loading slower ?

Comment: Why on earth are you still using something that old??? That must be a security nightmare...

Answer (score 0):

There are several option, that might cause your problems:

- Slow network between your server and you
- HTTPS on a host with a weak CPU might have an influence
- Virus scanners on the host or client
- If it is a dynamic page, the contents have to be assembled before delivery
- ...

You would have to provide more information, if you want to drill this down.

Comment: From Firebug I have these times related to my 550KB js

2,33s blocking
1,09s waiting
28,69s receiving

Is it usefull ?
Indeed this server is on local network, if I access the jsp page from local network, it is very fast ! Thanks

Comment: Which JSP page??? Is that different to the HTML page you talked about before? Also: The most time seems to be spent actually receiving the content. Maybe you should check the server logs and watch a request in progress..

Comment: Yes it a JSP but problem is not server side. From Apache log

93.22.120.18 - - [25/Oct/2011:14:55:03 +0200] "GET /ib/action.do HTTP/1.1" 200 80405
93.22.120.18 - - [25/Oct/2011:14:55:05 +0200] "GET /ib/extjs/resources/css/ext-standard.css HTTP/1.1" 200 176563
93.22.120.18 - - [25/Oct/2011:14:55:05 +0200] "GET /ib/extjs/ext.js HTTP/1.1" 200 175215
93.22.120.18 - - [25/Oct/2011:14:55:05 +0200] "GET /ib/app-all.js HTTP/1.1" 200 559769

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of the tomcat logs.. Apache logs are useless for these problems...

Comment: Rather odd.. Are you sure, you are using that Tomcat? Perhaps you should find somebody to have a look at it...

Comment: Yes, I'm sure ... they are updated only on tomcat startup/shutdown or if there is some error